# Typescript, index one interface keys using another interface

Tags: typescript

I have two interfaces with identical optional keys, but different values:

```
interface Obj1 {
  a?: string
  b?: string
  c?: number 
}

interface Obj2 {
  a: boolean
  b: string
  c: number 
}
```

Obj1 is served as a function argument, the other, Obj2, is the return of that function. I want the return type to identify only the given keys on Obj1. So if Obj1 contained only `a` and `b` then Obj2 will contain only `a` and `b` as well.

I tried with the approach bellow, but I get a ts error `Type 'Property' cannot be used to index type 'ValueType'`

```
type Obj1KeysWithObj2Values<KeyType extends Obj1, ValueType extends Obj2> = {
  [Property in keyof KeyType]: ValueType[Property]
}
```

**UPDATE:** The function and its call

```
const myFunc = <T extends Obj1>({ a, b, c }: T) => {
  const returnObj: Partial<Obj2> = {}
  if (a) {
    returnObj.a = true
  }
  if (b) {
    returnObj.b = '1'
  }
  if (c) {
    returnObj.c = 20
  }
  return returnObj as Obj1KeysWithObj2Values<T, Obj2>
}

const resultObj = myFunc({ a: 'hello', b: 'hello' })
```

If you try it, then you see on `resultObj` you get what ever you pass to the function, as long as it is in interface Obj1, regardless of Obj2.

Comment: Would you update your question with the signature of the function you're trying to use this with?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Consider using [Pick<Type, Keys>](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#picktype-keys) which is a part of standard library:

```js
interface Obj1 {
 a?: string
 b?: string
 c?: string
}

interface Obj2 {
 a?: boolean
 b?: boolean
 c?: boolean
}

type Result = Pick<Obj2, keyof Obj1>
```

First argument represents source object, second argument represents a union of keys which should be picked

In your case, you also need to make an intersection of Obj1 keys and Obj2 keys:

```js
interface Obj1 {
  a?: string
  b?: string
  c?: number
}

interface Obj2 {
  a: boolean
  b: string
  c: number
}

const myFunc = <T extends Obj1>({ a, b, c }: T) => {
  const returnObj: Partial<Obj2> = {}
  if (a) {
    returnObj.a = true
  }
  if (b) {
    returnObj.b = '1'
  }
  if (c) {
    returnObj.c = 20
  }
  return returnObj as Pick<Obj2, keyof T & keyof Obj2>
}

const resultObj = myFunc({ a: 'hello', b: 'hello' })
```

[Playground](https://tsplay.dev/NB4qbW)

Comment: @captains-yossarian thank you for the reply. When I tried to use your approach as generic and to pass `Obj1` dynamically it did not work, any idea?

Comment: @URogel Please provide reproducible example and explain what did you expect

Comment: @URogel - For what it's worth, I'd use `typeof a !== "undefined"` rather than a truthy test in your implementation (though of course it depends on what you're doing): https://tsplay.dev/mbKJbW

Comment: @captain-yossarianfromUkraine very slick solution! Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

The issue is that although **you** know that `Obj2` will always have a superset of `Obj1`'s keys, TypeScript doesn't know that, so it needs reassuring. :-) If you want to use those generics, you can clear that error by using a conditional type to test that the property key is also present in `ValueType`:

```typescript
type Obj1KeysWithObj2Values<KeyType extends Obj1, ValueType extends Obj2> = {
    [Property in keyof KeyType]: Property extends keyof ValueType ? ValueType[Property] : never;
// −−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
};
```

[Playground example](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgPICMBWBGZBvAWAChlTk4B+ALmQGcwpQBzAbmLOXWroebZLIJu9RiFbEAvsWKhIsRCgyYATPnZlKNdAHttAGwhwQ-Dly26DRk4O479h45OlEwATwAOirNgDSEV7QA6sBgABZKygBqcHoArhC0ADx+rgAqHigQAB6QIAAmtGjeADTI0XEQ6Z7I2bkFRSoAfMgAvGoCpADaAApQ2p5QbsigyADW-towyClVEAC6NL390EO1EPmF466TZTHxs8gUuxWzPX0DbnPINCAQAG7Q-BL8xDCxIAhgwNogNVlwAFt3AYABTaLA0JTYACUkO8KSCIXCWCiewSiShpQizUIHWQAHp8cgAFKxejkZB5WIAgGuYZAgwA9ZgOBfH7qUhQCBgWJQX64jgcOA0cGYAB0cFaLTaACI4DLihzBegRVgxegpbL0AqlRwEKrxQhNcgZQgdXjnpIgA)

Comment: That said, there may be a simpler solution depending on how the function is actually using the types. If you can add the signature of the function to the question, I (or someone else) may be able to suggest something simpler.

Comment: I am not sure I understand the question, but maybe this solution helps: `Pick<Obj2, keyof Obj1>`

Comment: @captain-yossarianfromUkraine - I'm an eejit. :-D That's **dramatically** better than the above, I can't believe I didn't think of `Pick`. I suggest posting it, because it does answer the question as it stands now. I suspect there's some detail missing that may take the question another way, but that's true for the answer above as well; we can only work with what's in front of us.

Comment: happens with me all the time. Some times I publish extremely complicated recursive solution and somebody just puts oneliner :D

Comment: I suggest to to make key index like this: `[K in keyof KeyType as K extends keyof ValueType ? K : never]` so you will only have props matched between two types.

Comment: @Adnan - I started with that, but it [doesn't work](https://tsplay.dev/NnerVw) because TypeScript doesn't narrow `Property` in the value part of the type expression, which is why I did it as above. *(But I'm deleting this, `Pick` is much better.)*

Comment: I had deleted this, but the OP posted saying they preferred this for some reason, so I've undeleted it (at least for now).

Answer (score 0):

This [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75070299/12348028) is completely `generic` and it works.

I just want to share something similar which I did to convert `Date` to a custom `DateTimeFormatParts` formatted date using `Intl`, except it's partially generic.

It worked like this:

```
// Accepts T which has any or all Intl.DateTimeFormatOptions properties
export type DateFormatPartsRecord<T extends Intl.DateTimeFormatOptions = Intl.DateTimeFormatOptions> = {
  // modify keys to match props with result props
  [P in keyof T as P extends "fractionalSecondDigits"
    ? "fractionalSecond"
    : P extends "hour12"
    ? "dayPeriod"
    : P]?: string;
};

// argument type for my caller function
export type DateIntlOptions<T extends Intl.DateTimeFormatOptions = Intl.DateTimeFormatOptions> = {
  locale?: string | string[];
  options?: T;
};

// the function which converts formatted intl array parts to my custom object type.
export function ToDateFormatParts<T extends Intl.DateTimeFormatOptions = Intl.DateTimeFormatOptions>(
  val: number | string | Date,
  intl?: DateIntlOptions<T>
): DateFormatPartsRecord<T> {
  const toFormat = new Date(val);
  const reduced: DateFormatPartsRecord<T> = {};
  Intl.DateTimeFormat(intl?.locale, intl?.options ?? { day: "2-digit", month: "short", year: "numeric" })
    .formatToParts(toFormat)
    .forEach(({ type, value }) => {
      if (type === "literal") return;
      reduced[type] = value;
    });
  return reduced;
}
```

---

Applying this to your case,
you can create a custom type based on the original:

```
// instead of obj2 interface:
type Obj2FromObj1<T extends Obj1> = {
  [K extends keyof T]: boolean;
} // or a shorter version: Record<keyof T, boolean>
```

So now you can create a function to return only what props defined in the obj1:

```
function Obj2ValuesFromObj1<T extends Obj1>(args: T): Obj2FromObj1<T> {
  // your handling here.
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is not my code, though it is still a valuable answer. It was posted by another user and shortly after the answer was removed so I don't know to whom to give the credit.

```
type Obj1KeysWithObj2Values<KeyType extends Obj1, ValueType extends Obj2> = {
  [Property in keyof KeyType]: Property extends keyof ValueType ? ValueType[Property] : never;
};
```

My explanation to it, though feel free to improve it, `Obj1KeysWithObj2Values` is generic type which accepts two params:

1. `KeyType` which extends the function param type.
2. `ValueType` which extends the function return type.

Then it is declaring a new type which is an object with keys as the keys in the `KeyType` and the values types, if they can be found on the `ValueType` will inherit the type from there or will be `never`.

Comment: It was [mine](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75070299/157247), I've undeleted it if you found it helpful. But why do you prefer this over `Pick`?

Comment: @T.J.Crowder your solution worked, the `Pick` solution needed some modification to fit my use case.
Thanks, I learned something useful none the less!